# Node.js oracledb module -- TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I am trying to run simple SQL statements using Oracledb npm for Nodejs. This has worked in the past with no issue but suddenly I am getting this error in a different environment. Possibly due to aliases? I am not sure.

The goal of the line causing the issue is to close out the connection once it completes or fails. I found the logic directly in the docs from Oracle found here: http://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#connectionclose

Really would appreciate any help!

```js
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const async = require('async');
const {getAwsSecret} = require('./awssecret');
var alias = "";

async function initialize() {
  // Set Oracle Pool Settings
  let hrPool = {
    poolMin: 10,
    poolMax: 10,
    poolIncrement: 0
  }

  var secret = await getAwsSecret('MAIN');
  const secretJSON = JSON.parse(secret);
  hrPool.user = secretJSON[process.env.CURENV + 'username'];
  hrPool.password = secretJSON[process.env.CURENV + 'password'];
  hrPool.connectString = secretJSON[process.env.CURENV + 'host'] + '/' + secretJSON[process.env.CURENV + 'dbname'];
  hrPool.poolAlias = secretJSON.alias;
  alias = secretJSON.alias;

  try { 
  await oracledb.createPool(hrPool);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

module.exports.initialize = initialize;

async function close() {
  await oracledb.getPool().close();
}

module.exports.close = close;

async function simpleExecute(statement, binds = [],clientdetails = [], opts = {}) {
    let conn;
    opts.outFormat = oracledb.OBJECT;
    opts.autoCommit = true;
    try {
      // Get Connection
      conn = await oracledb.getConnection(alias);
      // Run Query
      const result = await conn.execute(statement, binds, opts);
    ///////////// POST EXECUTION HANDLING /////////////
    if (conn) { // conn assignment worked, need to close
      try {
        // Close Connection
        await conn.close();
        // Return Result
        return result;
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
    ///////////// POST EXECUTION HANDLING /////////////
    } catch (err) {
      await conn.close();

    } 
  }

module.exports.simpleExecute = simpleExecute;
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined 2021-04-23T14:36:51.269-04:00  at 
Object.simpleExecute (/usr/src/app/services/database.js:59:18)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is an error getting the connection, your catch block calls `conn.close()` without having a valid `conn`.  This gives the error you see.  It may not be the only cause, but tidying the code will help.

Your `conn.close()` could be just once in a `finally()` block.  Look at examples like [example.js](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/example.js) e.g. like:

```
  let connection;

  try {
    connection = await oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig);

    result = await connection.execute(sql, binds, options);
    console.dir(result, { depth: null });

  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    if (connection) {
      try {
        await connection.close();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
```

Some other tips:

- If you code is going to execute a few statements consecutively then don't do a `getConnection()`/`close()` around each.  This affects pool scalability because there is some latching on the shared pool resource, and it adds extra code to the whole step.
- Avoid always committing.  This can destroy transactional consistency and add overhead if done unnecessarily.
- Use an explicit `drainTime` in the `pool.close()` call to ensure it is closed, see [webapp.js](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/webapp.js).

Comment: Thank you for your info -- based onwhat you have above where are you actually using pool.close()? It looks like it is just using the standard connection.close() attribute of connection. I fear I may be confusing the two and causing myself more problems. I now don't believe my code ever actually calls the close pool (versus connection).

Comment: One other question -- in that example above where is it actually returning the result? I am using these oracle calls to return data back to my frontend. (I do not see a return result).

Comment: You can close the pool at app shutdown.  For a web app like [webapp.js](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/webapp.js) this is when the process is halted.  Regarding returning data, replace the `console.dir` line with a return.

Comment: Thanks again, lastly if you don't mind I have one more question. If I were to use pool aliases would it change anything? I may have a use case in the future where the alias will be client specific to leverage using Oracle VPD based on the login.

Comment: Pool [aliases](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#createpoolpoolattrspoolalias) won't affect anything.  If each Node.js process only has one pool then you won't really need to change the default pool alias.  For VPD, look at using [`connection.clientID`](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#propconnclientid) instead of having multiple pools.

Comment: Thanks again Christopher. Of course now I have one more question -- I have made these updates and deployed to AWS. When I login to my site and begin to run I see 8 sessions in v$session with the correct connection id and setting I set. My question is do I need to worry about killing these sessions?

Comment: I'd say no, but it does depend on your resource requirements.  It would be better if you could open a new SO post (or ask at https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues) and give more detail about your code and deployment requirements.

Comment: Thanks again -- I have posted a new SO post with as much detail as I could think to add. Any input would be appreciated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67300535/how-can-i-better-optimize-my-nodejs-oracledb-environment-for-availability-secur